# Make a HTML link that does nothing (literally nothing)

Tags: html, css

I want a link that does nothing.  I don't want this:

`<a href="#">`

because then the URL becomes `something.com/whatever/#`.

The only reason I want a link is so the user can see that they can click on the text.  JavaScript is being used to perform some action so I don't need the link to go anywhere but I need it to look like a link!

I could use some data attribute and tell me CSS to make elements look like links if they have this attribute but it seems a bit overkill.

Comment: What's wrong with `something.com/whatever/#` ?

Comment: you could give it an href of blank and return false in the the javascript. But it's more semantic if you just change the cursor property to `pointer` in your CSS

Comment: @CharlesSprayberry: There are situations that you don't want it.

Comment: This would be a good question to ask on http://ux.stackexchange.com/ as well.

Comment: This question is discussed in more depth here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-attribute-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0

Comment: # causes the browser to jump to the top of the page. It also updates the hash property which can affect your code.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

The following will prevent your href from being ran

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false;">
```

If you are using jQuery, [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) can be used

Comment: Causes additional onclick events to be cancelled.

Comment: Causes page to scroll to the top.

Comment: @DavidHempy I don't experience this. Which browser?

Comment: @curt Google Chrome
Version 63.0.3239.84 (Official Build) (64-bit)  (or possibly a slightly-older version two weeks ago)

Comment: This doesnt work for wordpress plugin scroll to id and link will still do something. In this case, it will be buggy thing that will redirect you on the top of the page.

Comment: If `href="#"` causes issues try `href=""`.

Answer (score 137):

Try this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);">link</a>
```

Comment: +1  but quick question: is there a difference between `javascript:void` and `javascript:void(0)`?

Comment: If you will try use javascript:void(0) without param you will have SyntaxError and all your scripts will be failed.

Comment: @alexdets `javascript:void()` will be SyntaxError, but `javascript:void` just returns undefined - same as `void(0)`. Adam, as far as I can tell, `void` and `void(0)` are functionally equivalent for this use.  --- edit: although i see other comments that hint it might reload the page..

Comment: Does it matter how you capitalize javaScript/javascript/JavaScript/Javascript ?

Comment: @TechyTimo No the capitalization does not matter, in-fact it should not be capitalized. I have submitted an edit.

Comment: This yields warnings, if your application uses [CSP Directives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy) that block inline script execution. Additionally, it's better to just write `javascript:;`, which has the same effect as your solution, but requires less characters to type.

Answer (score 58):

In HTML5, this is very simple. Just omit the `href` attribute.

```html
<a>Do Nothing</a>
```

From [MDN on the a tag href attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-href):

> **href**
>
> This was the single required attribute for anchors defining a hypertext source link, but is no longer required in HTML5.

## What about the hand cursor on hover?

The default styles for a browser may not change the cursor to a pointer, for `a` tags with no `href`. You can universally change this with the following CSS.

```css
a {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<a>Do Nothing</a>
```

However it's probably better to be more-selective about it, and apply it to only the elements you intend to add event handlers to.

## What about making it tab-focusable?

Just add `tabindex="0"` to the element.

```html
<a tabindex="0">Do Nothing</a>
```

## Does it makes sense to use an `a` tag without a link?

Usually no, it's probably better to use a `button` element instead, and style it with CSS. But whatever you use, avoid using an arbitrary element like `div` when possible, as this is not semantic at all.

Comment: With bootstrap 4, links that don't have an href don't get styled as links.

Comment: If you need to retain formatting due to some css definitions you can't fix or don't want to mess with, the href attribute maybe needed.  The void(0) solution is better in that case.

Comment: Something really random to note: if you're worried about WCAG compliance, this approach won't satisfy their requirements

Comment: @Dortimer not random at all, the internet should be accessible.

Answer (score 15):

Proper:

```
<a href="#;">Link</a>
```

Comment: Yes, '#' is defined as the top of the page, but any fragment string that doesn't match the id or name of an element in the document will do.  https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsing-the-web.html#find-a-potential-indicated-element

Comment: This is the only answer that works when you want to specify a no-action link in markdown. For example, when you have a project on GitHub and you want to use GitHub badges in your README.md, as I am doing here: https://github.com/mikenakis/Bathyscaphe, and you want some of the badges to not link to anything when clicked. All other solutions will either take you to the top of the page, or take you to another page that shows just the badge. This is the only solution that really does nothing.

Comment: @MikeNakis The badges don't need to be wrapped in a link.

Answer (score 13):

Don't make it a link (although it is prefered to do it) and style it with CSS so that it looks like a link:

```
p.not-a-link { text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer }
```

Or even better just make it a link and let the javascript function which is used `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the link.

Also add the link to the `href` so that users without JS enabled will still be able to use it (as a fallback).

Comment: +1 With the IE5.5 debate concluded, would a span be better than a p?

Comment: I prefer span. P could make a new row, while span doesnt

Answer (score 11):

`<a href="javascript:;">Link text</a>` - that's what I usually use

Comment: Won't this reload the page with some browsers?

Comment: @Curt: You;re right, mis-read the question. You've got a comment upvote out of it :-)

Comment: ... and I've got 2 downvotes, including one after editing it! Harsh!

Comment: Remove the first code, then I'll be allowed to remove my down vote :) It wont let me remove the downvote, its "locked"

Comment: Ta. My rep's up and down like Tower Bridge at the moment!

Comment: Which browsers does this affect, is it still an issue anymore? This would be preferred over `void(0)`, because it's surfaced in the status bar. I say that because I've users flag it as a bug/error (which it obviously isn't), so I think having it t is confusing to them.

Answer (score 7):

We can achieve that using javascript void which normally involves evaluation of an expression and returning undefined, which includes adding `javascript:void(0);` on the href.

The void operator is usually used merely to obtain an undefined primitive value, usually using “void(0)” (which is equivalent to “void 0”). In these cases, the global variable undefined can be used instead (assuming it has not been assigned to a non-default value).

```css
a {
  text-decoration: initial;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0);"> This link actually does nothing when clicked</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

@Curt's answer will work, but you can use a [cursor style](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/cursor.html) in css to make it look like a link without the bother of generated a bogus link.  Use hand or pointer depending on browser conformance.

Cross browser conformant pointer css (from [cursor style](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/cursor.html) guide):

```
element {
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}
```

Comment: @PeeHaa Just use pointer only if you *don't* want it to work in IE5.5 and earlier!

Comment: That's what I said! Please don't mention IE5.5 :P On a more serious note IE5.5 share is `0.17%`. If people still are on that version they don't deserve to browse the web

Answer (score 2):

one way which no one has mentioned is to point the href to an empty local file location like so

```
<a href='\\'>my dead link</a>
```

why? If you use a framework such as react or angular, the compiler will spit out some warnings which can make your log or console dirty. This technique will also prevent robots or spiders from incorrectly linking things.

Answer (score 0):

What if you use only css?

```
pointer-events: none;
```

```css
span, a {
    color: black;
    cursor: default;
    pointer-events: none;    
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<span>Normal text --> <a href="https://google.com">Link to google click me</a> <-- another text</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

just remove the `href` attribute. it's not necessary.

```
<a> a link </a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Text goes here
When clicked this link will do nothing except display a little javascript:void(0) in the corner

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

DONT USE `<a>`... instead use `<span class='style-like-link'>`
and then use the class to style it however you want.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using an anchor tag without a link itself, not to mention that there are many cases where it would make a lot _more_ sense to do so, rather than replace it with a pseudo-anchor tag. Not to mention styling one element to look like another but be implemented differently is bound to cause maintanence issues in the future

Comment: Agreed. It entirely depends on the use-case and what you're trying to accomplish. I merely provided this as an answer to help others know that this is AN option.

Comment: If that's the case, I would suggest editing it to use language that shows it's a possible alternative, rather than stating in caps not to use a standard anchor tag for this, when it's perfectly valid to do so