# How to get a link that do nothing

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I have created a search engine using Angular and Bootstrap. I have created different results tab as shown in image  [Tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHsyd.png) . Right clicking on tab does not show the option of a link as we get on any link. 
[link on right click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgMWW.png)
Currently I am using `<li>` tag and bootstrap to create the tabs of different result section. Here is the code for that

```
<ul type="none" id="search-options">
        <li [class.active_view]="Display('all')" (click)="docClick()">All</li>
        <li [class.active_view]="Display('images')" (click)="imageClick()">Images</li>
        <li [class.active_view]="Display('videos')" (click)="videoClick()">Videos</li>
        <li [class.active_view]="Display('news')" (click)="newsClick()">News</li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" id="settings" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
            Settings
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="settings" id="setting-dropdown">
            <li routerLink="/preferences">Search settings</li>
            <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#customization">Customization</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" id="tools" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
            Tools
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="tools" id="tool-dropdown">
            <li (click)="filterByContext()">Context Ranking</li>
            <li (click)="filterByDate()">Sort by Date</li>
            <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Advanced Search</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

After clicking on the link everything is handled by the functions which get executed on click event. All I want to do that is make that a link, so that user can open it in new tab and state of the app should not change at all. How that is possible? I have tried to do that using routing but things became more complicated. i also followed some answers from here [Make a HTML link that does nothing (literally nothing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260546/make-a-html-link-that-does-nothing-literally-nothing) but they do not work. Please help. I have tried all the answers from there opening link in new tab just disturbs the state of URL.

Comment: No I have tried all the answers from there. I want to get a effect like Google. Go to Google, Search for a query and right click on image section and open it in new tab it opens the image section as if it is opened in same tab.

Comment: Like @hev1 said, a link that doesn't go anywhere can be achieved by using <a>Link text</a>. The question is... why do you want this to be an <a> element? What are you expecting that element to do if it's not link to something? Why not use a simple <span> for example?

Comment: I think you need to edit your question then, that is not a link that does nothing.

Comment: I want to get it opened in a new tab. But currently right clicking on it does not give any option to open it in new tab. After using <a> tag I was getting that option but opening in new tab disturbs the URL.

Comment: @Jake please edit my question, the way you want. Actually I thought this question will help.

Comment: Only you know what you truly want out of this question, and it's a good question! Please, just try to word it very plain, simple, and include all of your code that is involved with this problem. I'm sure it will be a helpful question, but it needs some work.

Comment: Try your best and I'll see what I can do when I return.

Comment: Ok I am editing accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

Using `<a href="#"></a>` will make the page scroll to the top.

Use `javascript:void(0)`:

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)">Clicking here does nothing</a>
```

Or equivalently, use `javascript:;`:

```html
<a href="javascript:;">Clicking here does nothing</a>
```

Or, with HTML5, just omit the href attribute:

```html
<a>Clicking here does nothing</a>
```

You can use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the default action of the link from being taken.

```html
<a href="http://www.google.com">Valid Link</a><br>
<button id='hitMe'>Disable link</button>
<br/>
<button id="enable">Enable link</button>
<script>
document.getElementById('hitMe').onclick = function() { // button click
  document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(a =>{
   a.onclick = function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  });
};
document.getElementById("enable").onclick = function(){
  document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(a =>{
   a.onclick = null;
  });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank You for your help but I have tried this answer.

Comment: It opens new tab `about:blank`

Comment: For both of them?

Comment: Your second answer is incomplete and first one is not working.

Comment: Incomplete in what way?

Comment: In your second answer it is not acting like a link also.

Comment: Why do you need it to act like a link?

Comment: If you have an onClick event, it will still act like a link.

Comment: With Bootstrap, it should still work, provided the right class is given to the `<a>` element.

Answer (score 1):

By clicking the button, no more links will be followed.

Like this you still have the `hover` destination preview. Like `google.de` etc...

```js
document.getElementById('hitMe').onclick = function() { // button click
  [...document.querySelectorAll('a')].forEach(function(el){
    el.onclick = function( e ) { // all 'a'
      return false;
    }
  });
};
```

```html
<a href="https://google.com">Valid Link</a><br>
<button id='hitMe'>Disable link.</button>
```

Comment: You wanted a non-working link sir :D -  if there is a problem please tell me - but not by telling me _there is a problem_ - this is not copy&paste ready solution

Comment: ah maybe the preventDefault part - thats jQuery

Comment: @Pilan `event.preventDefault()` is actually native Javascript.

Comment: @SachinSinghedited the answer, works :) hev1 you are absolutely right, sorry, removed it :D

Comment: @Pilan No problem.

Answer (score 0):

use

> javascript:;

as href attribute
and add

> event.preventDefault()

onclick method.

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="event.preventDefault()">Click me</a>
```