# jQuery closest selector is not working and scroll & focus to a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

My html code is

```
  <div class="main">
      <div class="sub-1">
    <select>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="sub-2">
    <a href="#" class="tst">Hi</a>

  </div>

</div>
```

So i want to change color of text in select box when .tst clicked .

so i write code

```
$(".main .tst").on("click",function(){

        $(this).closest(".main > select").css("color","red");

        });
```

but it is not working .

Also when i click on the link then the page is scrolling up to the top .

> How can i change the scrolling to select element .

Please help

Comment: This is not how [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) works. It finds an ancestor of the current element, that select is not an ancestor of `.tst`.

Comment: Maybe a button or 'e.preventDefault()` as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260546/make-a-html-link-that-does-nothing-literally-nothing will provide your desired behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$(this).closest(".main").find('select').css("color","red");`

You can add `id = test` for select tag and update href for a tag `$(this).attr('href', '#test');`

```js
$(".main .tst").on("click",function(){

        $(this).closest(".main").find('select').css("color","red");
        $(this).attr('href', '#test');
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Test</h1>
<div class="main">
      <div class="sub-1">
    <select id="test">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="sub-2">
    <a href="#" class="tst">Hi</a>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you . Could you please check the scroll effect also

Comment: you can add id for select tag and update href for a tag

Answer (score 1):

Try using `parents()` jquery method

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".main .tst").on("click", function() {
    $(this).parents(".main").find("select").css("color", "red");
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="sub-1">
    <select>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="sub-2">
    <a href="#" class="tst">Hi</a>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you . Could you please check the scroll effect also

Comment: `$(this).closest(".main")` is more optimal. Also please don't just post answers with pure code, explain the difference and what was wrong in the original if you can.

Answer (score 1):

`closest` will not look in to the child  but it will select the parent then use `find` to select the `select` tag

```js
$(".tst").on("click", function() {
  $(this).closest(".main").find('select').css("color", "red");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="sub-1">
    <select>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="sub-2">
    <a href="#" class="tst">Hi</a>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other explain you could use either [`.parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) or [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/).

Note that using either:

```
$(this).parents(".main").find("select").css("color", "red");
```

or

```
$(this).closest(".main").find('select').css("color", "red");
```

would target all `select`.

The reason why when you click the link got scrolled to the top because you set `href="#"` replacing with `href="javascript:void(0)"` would solve the issue. See here for more explanation: [Which “href” value should I use for JavaScript links, “#” or “javascript:void(0)”?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/138233/3654837)

---

Adding more detailed selector would prevent targetting all `select` element:
For selecting which element if you only had one you could use [`.first()`](https://api.jquery.com/first/) if you had more than one and possibly more [`:nth-child(x)`](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_nthchild.asp) where `x` is the index of your element.

To scroll and focus to `select` you can use  [`.focus()`](https://api.jquery.com/focus/). To smoothen the focus you could use [`.animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

```
$('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("select").first().offset().top
    }, 'slow');
$("select").first().focus();
```

See the following snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".main .tst").on("click", function() {
    //$(this).parents(".main").find("select").first().css("color", "red");
    $(this).closest(".main").find('select').first().css("color", "red"); // removing first() would target all select element
  });
  $(".main .tfse").on("click", function() {
    //$(this).parents(".main").find("select").first().css("color", "green");
    $(this).closest(".main").find('select').first().css("color", "green"); // removing first() would target all select element
    $("select").first().focus();
  });
  $(".main .tfsa").on("click", function() {
    //$(this).parents(".main").find("select").first().css("color", "orange");
    $(this).closest(".main").find('select').first().css("color", "orange"); // removing first() would target all select element
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("select").first().offset().top
    }, 'slow');
    $("select").first().focus();
  });
  $(".main .tise").on("click", function() {
    //$(this).parents(".main").find("select:nth-child(2)").css("color", "blue");
    $(this).closest(".main").find('select:nth-child(2)').css("color", "blue");
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("select:nth-child(2)").offset().top
    }, 'slow');
    $("select:nth-child(2)").focus();
  });
})
```

```css
.sub-2{
  margin-top:1600px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="sub-1">
    <select>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
    </select>
    
    <select>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="sub-2">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tst">Only affect but not focus (red, first)</a><br/>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tfse">Target and focus select element (green, first)</a><br/>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tfsa">Target, animate scroll and focus select element (orange, first)</a><br/>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tise">Target, animate scroll and focus select element based on your selected index - this example target second -> :nth-child(2) (blue, second)</a>
  </div>

</div>
```