# How to make HREF link to Nothing while having target _blank without JS inside Modal?

Tags: html, href, target

i am using this inside Modal:

```
<a target="_blank" 
   id="changeme" 
   rel="noopener noreferrer" 
   href="javascript:void(0)"
>
  Visit Site here
</a>
```

but it still opens a new tab.  Other answers were without `target="_blank"` tag.

Is it possible without using JS to make the link does nothing when clicked?

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260546/make-a-html-link-that-does-nothing-literally-nothing

Comment: Sorry, i could not post the ahref tag in the question, but your link is missing target="_blank". my example is: "a target="_blank" id="changeme" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="">Visit Site here</a"

Comment: So you want to leave the `target="_blank"` inside the <a></a>, make the link unclickable, but still leave it looking like a link.  Is that correct?

Comment: I assume you have some auto-generating code that requires you to leave in the `"target="_blank"` attribute.  I think you're going to have a hard time making this work on all browsers.

Apart from the "how" part of your question, what is the "why"?  What is your end goal for a user viewing the page with this link?

Comment: I think this one does what you want - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955667/disabled-href-tag/13955695