# attempting to return a Clickable image in javascript but onclick causes page refresh

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using JS to return a HTML clickable image in my web application.

The problem I'm running into is that when I click on the button, the image button automatically causes the page to refresh. What I'd like to do is ensure that when the button is clicked, no refresh takes place, I stay on the page and nothing changes:

```
 function BuildClickableImage()
 {
    var image = "";
        image  += "<a href='' ";
        image  += "  onclick =\"Method1();  \">";  //Currently no implementation for this method, its empty
        image  += "    <img src='@Url.Content("~/Pics/Pic1.png")' />";
        image  += "</a>";

   return image;
 }
```

Anyway to prevent refresh of the page when this is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of HTML5 you can simply omit the `href` attribute of the anchor:

```js
function BuildClickableImage()
 {
    var image = "";
        image  += "<a ";
        image  += "  onclick =\"Method1();  \">";  //Currently no implementation for this method, its empty
        image  += "    <img src='@Url.Content("~/Pics/Pic1.png")' />";
        image  += "</a>";

   return image;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

[Make a HTML link that does nothing (literally nothing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260546/make-a-html-link-that-does-nothing-literally-nothing)

```
function BuildClickableImage()
 {
    var image = "";
        image  += "<a href='#;' ";
        image  += "  onclick =\"Method1();  \">";  //Currently no implementation for this method, its empty
        image  += "    <img src='@Url.Content("~/Pics/Pic1.png")' />";
        image  += "</a>";

   return image;
 }
```

Or am I misunderstanding the problem?